# Gcloud App Engine: connection to Google Cloud SQL

Tags: node.js, google-app-engine, authorization, google-cloud-sql, gcloud

Nodejs application connects to database from localhost, but throws error after deployment:

From mysqljs:

```
Error: Cannot enqueue Query after fatal error. at Protocol._validateEnqueue
```

The http request returns status code `500`

I am pretty sure that the issue is about authorization. App Engine is in **the same project as SQL**, however I've added app to the Authorize apps of SQL Instance:

```
gcloud sql instances patch <sql-instance> --authorized-gae-apps <app-name>
```

but this still did not work

Is there a way to test db connection?

Comment: You should look at the logs to see what the specific error is. Feel free to update your question with the stack trace of the error and we might be able to help further.

Comment: @alpeware SQL Database returns no errors, HTTP server logs error which I have already indicated